# journal file stuck when azcopy is aborted

Tags: azure, azcopy

Thanks in advance, 
I'm creating a copy solution using PowerShell and will put the PS file in task scheduler. This PS file will contain azcopy cmdlet. I want to make sure my script runs fine even in the middle of copy and server crashed then at the next schedule run my azcopy script should run and shouldn't fail because of the below reason.

I've one concern with azcopy. When i start copying of data and press ctrl + C OR my machine is restarted in the middle of copy. azcopy journal file is stuck **AzCopy.jnl** & **AzCopyCheckpoint.jnl** are the 2 files which is corrupted and stuck. We have to delete the files and then the next azcopy completes when i delete it until then no further azcopy will complete.
azcopy parameter which I'm currently using is to only copy new files is mentioned below

```
azcopy.exe /Source:E:\Datatesting\ /Dest:$deststorageaccount /DestKey:$Destkey /S /XO /XN
```

So what I'm thinking is to delete all the files inside the azcopy journal folder before my script runs.

Q1. ) so deleting the journal file if it is present, is it supported what I'm trying to do? as my azcopy command checks for /XO and /XN and only copy the files which are not present on azure blob then it shouldn't matter if azcopy doesn't finds any actual failed job with help of journal file

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tried v10 which went GA recently and this issue is not seen.

Comment: Yes. FYI, there are no journal files in v10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what you meant by **corrupted and stuck**? It's not expected that Ctrl + C will corrupt the journal files of AzCopy. Is stuck just due to a confirmation prompt about whether to leverage the existing journal files detected? If that's the case, you can specify `/Y` in the AzCopy command line to suppress the prompt directly.

Comment: no i don't get that prompt as my azcopy command doesn't change. I use the same paramaters and the issue you are pointing at occurs when we have journal file and our paramater of azcopy is changed. Can you try it on your side? if ongoing copy is happening and you press ctrl + C or your azcopy process is crashed may be because of the server is crashed or restarted unexpectedly due to system update then it generates a corrupt journal file. it is also mentioned by emma in below post    https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6356